# Egit: Cloning a repository via SSH

Tags: eclipse, git, egit, git-clone

I'm trying to clone a remote repository via SSH using EGit.

I've made some progress by setting http.sslverify to false and turning up the remote connection timeout.

Now the cloning makes progress, through "resolving deltas", but then hangs Eclipse with a full "loading" bar. There is no label on the bar and no apparent way to cancel the operation without force-quitting Eclipse.

I'm running Eclipse 3.7.0 and Mac OS 10.5.8.

Any ideas? I'm not sure what to do because I have no error message -- just no progress.

(BTW, I originally posted this as an "answer" in another thread. My post was deleted. I apologize for the breach of etiquette and can only say that I'm new here. I'm a bit perplexed that I didn't get any notification that my post had been deleted; I had to search again to find the thread and scroll down to see the message.)

Answer (score 0):

Peter, just curious as to where you host your repository? If you had a timeout issue, it's possible the host has even more issues.

Have you tried running the git clone from the command line and use EGit only for the "mundane" tasks? It's not ideal, but being able to do it from the command line usually saves a lot of trouble, and if it fails the error messages are very clear about why.

I've used EGit a while, but went back to just opening a terminal and doing the sacro-sanct

- git commit -a
- git fetch origin/master (or whatever your branch is)
- git merge
- git push

EGit tends to fail for weird reasons. And when using with Github it becomes a nightmare to set it up to use SSH keys.

Comment: My repository, created with EGit, is on another machine within my domain.

I tried to use the command-line version of Git, only to find that it wasn't installed on the machine on which I wish to clone the repository. I tried to install Git. The version for which there is a Mac installer requires Mac OS 10.6, and of course I'm running 10.5. Older versions of Git are available, but apparently have to be compiled from source -- and, of course, the makefile doesn't work.

I used Egit very successfully last semester for a project involving 15 students. We were able to clone, fetch, and push...

Comment: ...with impunity when working with different accounts and machines sharing a file system.

Comment: With a little more work, I was able to get a working command-line version of Git installed. That allowed me to clone across SSH. Now, however, cloning across the file system produces a similar hang. Bizarre -- this was working a couple of months ago, and I can't think of anything that has changed.

Comment: I think it may simply have been a problem with the switch to 10.7 - I have a friend using OS X and git professionally and he keeps complaining that he should've stayed on 10.6. EGit of course won't work without the command line utilities installed, and won't complain if they're not present.